# React - 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I added `Truncate-react` to my project. After that, React tells me I need to install `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, which I did in  **package.json** file in this way:

```json
      "babel": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
              "loose": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
```

Of course, the `proposal-class-properties` itself I installed with the label **--save-dev**

but after all this, I still get an error that looks like this [image: this]

Comment: What babel version do you have? 
How are you using babel? with webpack?

Comment: @Liron `"@babel/core": "7.9.0"` using just in react via `npm run eject` and i wrote babel code in **package.json**

Comment: Is there a way you can share your project?

Comment: @Liron https://github.com/AndreyFreiz/Hulu repos

Comment: ok.. so you have to do 2 things to make it work.

1. you have both .babelrc file and babel config in your package.json. you have choose one.

2. You have to change `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate/src/TextTruncate'` to `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate' in VideoCard component.
I assume react-text-truncate/src/TextTruncate this file is not the compiled version

Comment: @Liron replace this comment to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the github link you sent you have to do 2 things to make it work

1. you have both .babelrc file and babel config in your package.json. you have to choose one.
2. You have to change `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate/src/TextTruncate'` to
   `import TextTruncate from 'react-text-truncate'` in VideoCard component.
   I assume react-text-truncate/src/TextTruncate this file is not the compiled version